# Adobe PDF not showing on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iis

I got this code below working on local `(using source code)` perfectly fine. But when I published it on `IIS7` the `PDF` is not showing anymore.. Is there a problem with the IIS or ?. . . I spent many days on this problem.

```
Dim strPath = Server.MapPath("~\Reports\GeneratedReport.pdf")

my_rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, strPath)
Dim file = New System.IO.FileInfo(strPath)
Dim Process = New Process()
If file.Exists Then
    Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Process.StartInfo.FileName = strPath
    Process.Start()
Else
    'No Report found
End If
```

As you can notice in the picture below you see the AdobeReader is running but its not displaying on my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "not showing" I am assuming you want the PDF to be opened on the client, not the server. Normally you would send the file to the browser. `Process.Start()` will start a process server-side, so even if the AppPool is allowed to start a process, it will only open the pdf on the server.
Below is how you send a file from the server to the client.

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/reports/GeneratedReport.pdf");

//read the file from disk and convert to a byte array
byte[] bin = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);

//clear the buffer stream
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

//set the correct contenttype
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

//set the correct length of the data being send
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());

//set the filename for the file
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"GeneratedReport.pdf\"");

//send the byte array to the browser
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

//cleanup
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

VB

```
Dim strPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/reports/GeneratedReport.pdf")

'read the file from disk and convert to a byte array
Dim bin() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath)

'clear the buffer stream
Response.ClearHeaders
Response.Clear
Response.Buffer = true

'set the correct contenttype
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

'set the correct length of the data being send
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString)

'set the filename for the file
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""GeneratedReport.pdf"""")", send the byte array to the browser, Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length))

'cleanup
Response.Flush
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest
```

Comment: Not if you want to download a file from the server to the client.

Comment: I tested your code and working fine.. But its downloading the PDF.. Is there any alternative way of `Response.Flush` ?. Just like displaying it

Comment: Flushing has nothing to do with the client side handling of the PDF. You cannot control what will happen to the file once it is send. From then on the client is in conrol. Depending of the browser type and user preferences it is opened, saved to disk etc.

Comment: I just notice it when it passing in flush it download the PDF. That's why I ask if there is an alternative way w/o downloading it?. Just display it in the screen just like opening a normal PDF File.

Comment: No, showing it on the screen is done by the browser/pdf reader on the client. You cannot force it. My settings for example are always asking what should happen to a file when downloaded, not opening them directly.

Comment: Okay thanks this helps me.. But I need to ask first the owner of the current system. I'm just helping him. BTW I will accept this as an answer.. If the owner satisfied I will give the bounty.

Comment: Thanks.. It was great. :).. BTW one last question.. After downloading it can I rename it something like GeneratedReport + Date Today?. `GeneratedReport_04172017`

Comment: Sure, you do something like this: `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"GeneratedReport_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf\"");`

Comment: I got an error.. `Comma, ')', or valid expression continuation expected`

Comment: How about this (the last was C# code): `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", ("attachment; filename=""GeneratedReport_" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf"""")")))`

Comment: and now it says `GeneratedReport is not declared. It maybe inaccessible due to protection level`. same as the ddMMyyyy.  and the pdf is `pdf is not a member of string`

Comment: Just add `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")` after the filename. Maybe the online code translator I used screwed things up.

Comment: I use this code ` Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""GeneratedReport  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + """ .pdf""")`.. But it gives me `GeneratedReport  04-17-2017-`. I don't want the last `-`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a PDF on your site, here are a few javascript tools you can use that can help you accomplish this:

http://viewerjs.org/

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Personally, I have not used either of these tools, but they seem like they would be sufficient for what you are trying to accomplish.