# How to get HTTP Response while export to excel on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Developing RDLC report with export to excel functionality on button click in Asp.net. below code where i am using while button click i am not getting http response please help me how it will get http response
,Thanks

```
    public void btnExportAll_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = ddl.SelectedValue;
        string Type = Productddl.SelectedValue;
        string Id =  ddl.SelectedValue;
        DateTime BD = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetCashDataSource(BD, Name, Convert.ToInt32(Id), Flag);
        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        string filename;
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = 
        Server.MapPath("~/RDLCReports/ReportExport.rdlc");
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new 
        ReportDataSource("Balance", ds.Tables[0]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new 
        ReportDataSource("Name", ds.Tables[1]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new 
        ReportDataSource("Amount", ds.Tables[2]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Amount", 
        ds.Tables[3]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("GrandTotal", ds.Tables[4]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Diff", ds.Tables[5]));
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Name", ds.Tables[6]));
        viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
        string Code = "10,12";
        ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("BusinessDate", txtDate.Text, false);
        ReportParameter rp2 = new ReportParameter("DropDown", ddl.SelectedValue, false);
        ReportParameter rp3 = new ReportParameter("Id", Code, false);
        viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1, rp2, rp3 })
        byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(
           "Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
            out extension,
           out streamids, out warnings);
        filename = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "ExportToExcel", "xls");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        try
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "alert('Error while generating PDF.');", true);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

      Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/RDLCReports/ReportExport.rdlc"));
         Response.End();
         viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get HTTP Response`? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: After Executing above code file is not downloading

Comment: I am Expecting excel file will export properly

Comment: Start by sending 1 file, not 2 (`Response.BinaryWrite` OR `Response.WriteFile`, not both)

Comment: Thanks As you said i tried but it is not working

Comment: Check my answer here. It shows how to send a file from disk to the client http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270631/adobe-pdf-not-showing-on-iis7

Comment: Someone can help me ?