# How to display PDF file bytes in a new tab or window

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I have a method that generates a PDF as an array of bytes, I want to display this byte array (as PDF) inside a new tab at the browser.

Here's a piece of the code

```
protected void BtnDisplayPdf_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    byte[] pdf = PdfManager.GeneratePdf(/*some inputs*/);
    //open the above bytes at a new tab as a PDF file
}
```

How to do that? I want to display it as PDF without saving the file physically!

Comment: (If you use MVC) Create an Action that returns the PDF (bytes) and on a link call the Action and open it in a new tab.

Comment: is this MVC? or old-style asp.net? but ultimately it should just be a case of sending back the bytes with the correct content-type ("application/pdf") and content-disposition ("inline") headers

Comment: No, it's asp.net web forms

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322319/5836671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
byte[] bin = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"GeneratedReport.pdf\"");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```