# ASP.net host closed the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to stop this warning in IIS and I am reading that I should check this object `IsClientConnected` before I call `TransmitFile(filename)` . Is this correct or is Another way to correct this ?

IIS exception

> Exception information: 
>      Exception type: HttpException 
>      Exception message: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800703E3.
>     at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean ?throwOnDisconnect)

```
    if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "-1");
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.TransmitFile(filename);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

updated Code

```
            try
            {

                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "-1");
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                context.Response.TransmitFile(filename);
                context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
                //context.Response.Flush();
                //context.Response.End();
            }
            catch (HttpException hex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: don't call `Flush` and `End`. let the server handle that for you.

Comment: Think the only way to handle it is to [`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) the exception.

Comment: @JohnWu is it just an catch(HttpException hex) or is there something else?

Comment: @DanielA.White is `Flush` and `End` the problem? what about `TransmitFile`?`

Comment: I believe transmit file should be ok

Comment: should I use `context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322319/5836671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error implies that there is a ***Runtime Exception*** in your code. Usually, when hosting your app through the IIS there are such errors which will close the connection immediately.

You should debug your code by attaching to the process ***w3wp***.

By navigating in Visual Studio to:

```
---> DEBUG
   ---> Attach to process
   ---> choose w3wp.exe
   ---> attach to process
```

The troubleshooter implies you to check the `IsClientConnected` object because it is the most common issue that will likely to cause the exception - if you are trying to call the client which does not exists (`IsClientConnected` is `null` for example).

Comment: thanks Should I just catch the error and remove the IsClientConnected?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best option.